# Excel matrix to R matrix for bipartite network analysis: conversion issue

Tags: r, excel, networking, matrix, bipartite

I am new/inept using R. I have bipartite pollinator network data in a matrix format in excel- superficially similar to the Safariland dataset but unlike Safariland data I am unable to perform functions such as "networklevel" or "visweb".

I have tried multiple ways to include column 1 as row headers but do not fully understand why I cannot do so. My data appears to be a table dataframe.

I have tried

```
as.matrix(MYDATA, row.names.data.frame(1)
head(MYDATA, Inf)
data.matrix(MYDATA, rownames.force= NA)
read.table(file= MYDATA, row.names= 1)
```

To make my data into a suitable matrix for analysis in the bipartite package.

Any advice? [Image: Imported CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOXOj.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original csv file? That will helps a lot. Besides, in R, all data in a matrix must be of the same type, numeric, strings and etc. So you either need to read the data with the rownames correctly to convert it to a numeric matrix, or need to translate the dataframe without the first column to a numeric matrix.

Comment: This works for me: `myfile <- " A B C\na 1 0 0\nb 0 1 0\nc 0 0 1";df <- read.table(text = myfile, row.names = 1);igraph::graph_from_incidence_matrix(df)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
myfile <- read.table(file="myfile.csv", h=T, sep=";", row.names = 1)
```